# No se encuentra instancia en SQl Server- Error 53

Tags: sql-server

de entrada indico que ya he realizado la desinstalación de todo y he vuelto a reinstalar 5 veces y estoy desesperada por una solución, no he podido estudiar nada para el parcial y me urge hallar una solución :(

Tengo un problema con el SQL Server 2017 ,ya que al conectarme y autentificarlo con Windows me aparece un error 53.

El cual dice que no se encontró la ruta especifica de la instancia para conectarse. Abrí el SQL Server Configuration Manager pero no me aparece ninguna instancia para habilitarla, y quise iniciar el servicio de SQL Server desde el administrador de tareas y aparece que no está instalado y no se puede iniciar. ¿Cómo resuelvo este problema?

Ya que lo desinstalé y lo volví a instalar, el SQL Server y no me deja porque no encuentra ninguna instancia.

Comment: Es probable que no estés instalando SQL Server, y en lugar de eso estés instalando solo SQL Server Management Studio o algún otro paquete. Al momento de hacer la instalación especifica que quieres instalar el motor de base de datos. Chécate este video, puede ser de ayuda https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOpgvtHfYjY

Comment: Si abres Services.msc puedes ver el Servicio de SQl Server en la lista de servicios?

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya fue solucionado